# How to implement many-to-many relationship between a dimension and the fact table in Iccube?

Tags: modeling

I need help to implement the following example in [icCube](https://www.iccube.com): A patient can have many dental procedures (the same example applies to diagnostics). The key here is that it must be a many-to-many relationship between the procedure dimension and the table of facts, across a bridge table.
Some contribution would help me a lot.

[image: The star scheme consists of the tables: patient, procedure, fact table, and bridge table linking procedure and the fact table, the fact table has a primary key, and the bridge has a key composed of the table key of facts and the key to the procedure]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of setting up many-to-many relations in icCube: [Many-to-Many using a Bridge Table](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/facts_many2many_bridges.php) and [Many-to-Many dimensions](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_many2many.php).

A step-by-step tutorial article explaining how to set up both methods is also available [here](https://www.iccube.com/support/understanding-many-to-many-relations/).

Please note we at icCube use stackoverflow quoting "iccube" as support channel: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iccube

Thanks for posting your next questions through there!
Hope it helps!